# Datasets with x,y coordinates of ball, puck and other sports balls/projectiles

Tags: data-request, sports

I want to train TrackNet more because its accuracy is not that good.

[TrackNet Gitlab repo](https://nol.cs.nctu.edu.tw:234/TzuHanHsu/TrackNet)

The tracked tennis ball wobbles unnaturally on tosses for serves, etc.

So I figured that following the intuition of tensor2tensor and other transfer learning schemes of training TrackNet on other sports or other projectile videos and images where the x,y coordinates of the object being tracked on the 2D video frame are provided.

I am probably going to use VGG annotator to create more tennis specific data and post in on Github but in the meantime if anyone knows of any public datasets out there, please let me know.

Comment: [PITCHf/x](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PITCHf/x) data might be a good candidate.  One simple way to access this data is to use the [pitchRx](https://pitchrx.cpsievert.me/) package for R.

Comment: @sboysel it's to time to learn R!  I was debating between Octave and R the other day.